# Getting max values based on sliced column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's consider this Dataframe:

```
$> df
   a    b    
0  6   50   
1  2   20    
2  9   60   
3  4   40   
4  5   20
```

I want to compute column D based on:

- The max value between:

  - integer 0
  - A slice of column B at that row's index

So I have created a column C (all zeroes) in my dataframe in order use `DataFrame.max(axis=1)`. However, short of using apply or looping over the DataFrame, I don't know how to slice the input values. Expected result would be:

```
$> df
   a    b  c    d
0  6   50  0   60
1  2   20  0   60
2  9   60  0   60
3  4   40  0   40
4  5   20  0   20
```

So essentially, d's 3rd row is computed (pseudo-code) as `max(df[3:,"b"], df[3:,"c"])`, and similarly for each row.

Since the input columns (b, c) have already been computed, there has to be a way to slice the input as I calculate each row for D without having to loop, as this is slow.

Comment: I don't think it does the same thing. It's true I want to avoid negative values, however I do want the maximum value from B up to that point. Your solution give me only the current value from the corresponding B row.

Comment: e.g. the 1st 2 rows for D are B's 3rd value, because 60 >50 and 60 >20

Comment: I see, you're looking for cummax but I wont share the exact code since I thought you did share a code you tried but that was pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this could work: Reverse "B", find `cummax`, then reverse it back and assign it to "d". Then use `where` on "d" to see if any value is less than 0:

```
df['d'] = df['b'][::-1].cummax()[::-1]
df['d'] = df['d'].where(df['d']>0, 0)
```

We can replace the last line with the one below using `clip` (thanks @Either), and drop the 2nd reversal (assuming indexes match) making it all a one liner:

```
df['d'] = df['b'][::-1].cummax().clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
   a   b   d
0  6  50  60
1  2  20  60
2  9  60  60
3  4  40  40
4  5  20  20
```

Comment: they have clip for your unreadable last line

Comment: (yes I'm bad with words.)

Comment: Yes that seems it would work - I'll test & accept if it does in my use cases. That feels pretty convoluted however, e.g. in Excel notation that would be something like =MAX(0, MAX(G4:$G$15)), I would have thought Panda provied something similar to auto-increment notatiON?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions it's pandas with s

Comment: @Either thanks. Edited it in. I knew there must be something better than that one :-)

Comment: @Either yes but I'm working on a small project, so a single panda is enough I think.

Comment: Minor comment - one could also call .clip() inline with .cummax()[::-1], since that returns a dataframe as well.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions that's what I was thinking as well. The indices match, so no need for the second reversal. Do you want to edit my answer to put it in?

Comment: @enke up to you really - whatever you think best for posterity and generations of futur pandaers.